# How to implement collection that speeds up searching by one or few element properties?

Tags: c#, performance, search, collections, find

I would to make custom collection in C#, that will provide fast search by one or few given properties of its element type. For example I have List of Component and Component class has a type (internal .NET property, but I would to have fast find for example of Light - which derives from Component) and unique HashTag (string - my own property). So I would to have something like FindByType(...) and FindByHashTag(...) methods on my own collection type, but in more "generic" way.

I use the word "generic" because this custom collection should be easily extensible for other properties.

It is possible to do this in C#, if so, how?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's wrong with `Dictionary<key,value>`?

Comment: Dictionary<key,value> speeds up by only one property in meaning of the question.

Comment: How about `Dictionary<Property,Dictionary<key,value>>`?

Comment: Beware of premature optimization. You may not _need_ a speedup in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code illustrates how you could have this done. Note that this assumes each property to be indexed is unique. In this example, EmployeeID is unique for each employee. In order to handle non-unique cases, you would need to modify the code to have something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<T>>> intIndexes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<T>>>();
```

instead of:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, T>> intIndexes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, T>>();
```

in addition, you have to redefine getByPropertyValue as follows:

```
public List<T> getByPropertyValue(string propertyName, int propertyValue)
```

Ideally, it would be nice to provide hints indicating wather the property is unique or not. This is no way a complete implementation, but you should get the idea on how to use reflection to achieve what you want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IndexerSampleCode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Indexer<Employee> indexer = new Indexer<Employee>();
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.EmployeeID = 45;
            e.FirstName = "Tarik";
            e.LastName = "Hoshan";
            e.BirthDate = new DateTime(1965, 2, 18);
            indexer.add(e);
            var e2 = indexer.getByPropertyValue("EmployeeID", 45);
            Console.WriteLine(e2.FirstName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Indexer<T>
    {
        // Collection of dictionories that will be used to index properties of type int
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, T>> intIndexes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, T>>();

        public Indexer() {
            System.Type indexerType = this.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;
            System.Type elementType = indexerType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var members = elementType.GetProperties();
            // Loop through each property and create a Dictionary corresponding to it
            foreach (var member in members)
            {
                if (member.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                {
                    intIndexes.Add(member.Name, new Dictionary<int, T>());
                }
            }
        }

        public T getByPropertyValue(string propertyName, int propertyValue)
        {
            Dictionary<int, T> index = intIndexes[propertyName];
            return index[propertyValue];
        }

        public void add(T o) {
            var type = o.GetType();
            var members = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var member in members)
            {
                if (member.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                {
                    var propertyName = member.Name;
                    Dictionary<int, T> index = intIndexes[propertyName];
                    int value = (int) o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o, null);
                    index.Add(value, o);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Sample test class
    class Employee
    {
        public DateTime BirthDate
        {
            set;
            get;
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            set;
            get;
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            set;
            get;
        }

        public int EmployeeID {
            set;
            get;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you can do that with Dictionary but with your custom class as Key.
In the custom class you must implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method and in `GetHashCode` you can return a hash that identify your custom class based on one or more property.

Comment: But I would to use once one property for search, once another property, and in certain situations both of them. Do I think correctly: your solution will work only when I want to search by all certain properties at once?